# Custom SpringBoot Bean Validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation

I'm creating an annotation to validate Start/End dates, I want to ensure they do not overlap.

Annotation:

```
@Documented
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { NonOverlappingDatesValidator.class })
public @interface NonOverlappingDates {

    String start();
    String end();

    String message() default "OVERLAPPING_OF_DATES";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    
}
```

Validator:

```
public class NonOverlappingDatesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NonOverlappingDates, Object> {

    private String start;

    private String end;

    /**
     * Initialize.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(NonOverlappingDates nonOverlappingDates) {
        start = nonOverlappingDates.start();
        end = nonOverlappingDates.end();
    }

    /**
     * Checks if is valid.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object instanceToValidate, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        Class<?> classToValidate = instanceToValidate.getClass();
        
        LocalDateTime startDate;
        LocalDateTime endDate;
        
        try {
            startDate = getLocalDateTimeFromFieldName(classToValidate, instanceToValidate, start);
            endDate = getLocalDateTimeFromFieldName(classToValidate, instanceToValidate, end);
        } catch (ReflectionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        
        return DateTimeUtils.isBefore(startDate, endDate);
    }
    
    private LocalDateTime getLocalDateTimeFromFieldName(Class<?> classToValidate, Object instanceToValidate, String fieldName) throws ReflectionException {
        Method getter = ReflectionUtils.getPublicGetterOfFieldName(classToValidate, fieldName);
        Object value = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(instanceToValidate, getter);
        if (value instanceof LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
            return localDateTime;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(fieldName+" is not a LocalDateTime");
        }
    }

}
```

DTO to be validated:

```
@Data
@NonOverlappingDates(start = "startDate", end = "endDate")
public class IdentityCardDTO {

    @JsonProperty
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    private String surname;

    @JsonProperty
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @JsonProperty
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @JsonProperty
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime endDate;
    
}
```

I'm wondering if instead of passing the fields name and then using Reflection to retrieve the value, it is possible to pass directly the value of the fields I want to validate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve such effect with abstraction for the data you need to validate. You need an interface with methods to get the data you need. Let's say:

```
public interface DatesData {

  LocalDateTime startDate();

  LocalDateTime endDate();
}
```

Not a really good name, but ok for example purposes. Then enable your actual validator to validate instances of this interface, not `Object` as it is now. Like this you can also simplify it a lot:

```
public class NonOverlappingDatesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NonOverlappingDates, DatesData> {

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(DatesData data, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return data.startDate().isBefore(data.endDate());
  }
}
```

`NonOverlappingDatesValidator` can now validate **any** class implementing `DatesData`. `IdentityCardDTO` becomes:

```
@Data
@NonOverlappingDates
public class IdentityCardDTO implements DatesData {

  //the rest of the fields, getters, setters, etc.

  @Override
  public LocalDateTime startDate() {
    return startDate;
  }

  @Override
  public LocalDateTime endDate() {
    return endDate;
  }
}
```

This simplifies `NonOverlappingDates` as well, since you no longer need `start()` and `end()` methods.