# How to avoid Jakarta validation annotations duplication when validating DTOs and Entities?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I'm trying to validate both DTOs (passed into controller methods) and JPA entities. But this often leads to validation rules duplication.

Validation rules applied are often similar both for entity and DTO classes, for example (classes simplified):

Product entity class has a name annotated with @NotEmpty:

```
@Entity
@Table
class Product {
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    // id, getters, setters and so on
}
```

NewProductRequest DTO class has @NotEmpty name too:

```
class NewProductRequest {
    @NotEmpty
    public String name;
}
```

In more complex scenarios, this leads to massive validation duplication.
Using this approach any validation changes applied to Product have to be applied to NewProductRequest as well.

Is there a way to avoid validation annotations duplication so one can follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)? Can it be achieved with Spring MVC custom validators?

Comment: You can avoid the duplication by abstracting away the data that needs validation using interfaces and writing `ConstraintValidator` for the interface. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76921231/custom-springboot-bean-validation/76921640#76921640) shows how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I really needed was annotating getters of an interface.

As Chaosfire [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76921640/21833389), one can get rid of the duplication by abstracting away the data that needs validation using interfaces and writing `ConstraintValidator` for the interface.

Merits of annotating getters of base classes are [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285499/21833389).

A solution for me will be annotating getters of interface (let's name it ValidProduct):

```
public interface ValidProduct {
    @NotEmpty
    String getName();
}
```

DTO and entity classes then implement this interface.
Product entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Product implements ValidProduct {
    private String name;
    
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

NewProductRequest DTO class then looks like:

```
public class NewProductRequest implements ValidProduct {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This can then be combined with JSR `ConstraintValidator` or Spring `Validator` implementations.